# How to create a tooltip behind a customizer setting label?

Tags: theme-customizer

I would like to show a tooltip after a setting label in customizer which on hover will show the help-text. I should be able to send the help-text from the control or setting registration like this:

```
$wp_customize->add_control( 'ghoul_test', array(
    'type'      => 'text',
    'label'     => __( 'Title', 'ghoul' ),
    'section'   => 'colors',
    'help-text' => __( 'This is help text.', 'ghoul' ),
) );
```

I can add the tooltip icon and worked out the hover part. But I am stuck on sending the help-text data.

Is this possible in core controls or not?

Anyone help is very much appreciated.

Comment: How are you building the tooltip. What tooltip script are you using or you code that yourself? If the tooltip-text can be added as an `data-attribute`, to the input, take a look at `input_attrs` parameter of `add_control`. From the codex: _Allows you to add attributes to the input. This extends beyond just using min, max, and step for number and range, to the ability to add custom classes, placeholders, the pattern attribute, and anything else you need to the input element._ [Look here.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Customize_Manager/add_control) Or create a custom control.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I want to do so in the default controls first without creating the custom ones. The problem I am facing is how to send the data to the default ones using the add_control parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can send the data via `input_attrs` parameter of `add_control`. However with that you can add attributes to the **input** field only.

Iam using **Tipr** here for the tooltips. You can find it [here](http://www.tipue.com/tipr/).
But you can also use other scripts or also the default bundled jQuery-UI.
[Default WP scripts in the codex.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/#default-scripts-included-and-registered-by-wordpress)

Also with this way no custom control is needed.

I created a new customizer section and add a setting and control to it:

```
//Add new section
$wp_customize->add_section( 'my_custom_section' , array(
    'title'      => __( 'My Section Name', 'textdomain' ),
) );

//Add new setting
$wp_customize->add_setting('text_setting', array(
    'default'        => 'Some default value',
) );
$wp_customize->add_control('text_setting', array(
    'label'   => __( 'My Setting', 'textdomain' ),
    'section' => 'my_custom_section',
    'type'    => 'text',
    'input_attrs' => array(
        'class' => 'has-tooltip', // add class to input element
        'data-tip' => 'My custom tooltip!', // add 'data-tip' attribute to input element
        'data-mode' => 'above', // add 'data-mode' attribute to input element
    ),
) );
```

Take a look at the `'input_attrs'` parameters of `add_control`.
Iam adding 3 different attributes to the `input` field, that means that the markup of the input field will be:

```
<input class="has-tooltip" data-tip="My custom tooltip!" data-mode="above" value="Some default value" data-customize-setting-link="text_setting" type="text">
```

After that we enqueue the tooltip scripts and style to the customizer via `customize_controls_enqueue_scripts`:

```
function custom_customizer_enqueue() {

    //Enqueue Tipr JS and CSS
    wp_enqueue_script( 'tipr-js', plugins_url('/tipr/tipr.min.js', __FILE__) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'tipr-css', plugins_url('/tipr/corso.css', __FILE__) );

    //Enqueue custom script to initialize the tooltips
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-init-script', plugins_url('/customizer.js', __FILE__), '', false, true );

}
add_action( 'customize_controls_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_customizer_enqueue' );
```

Now we just need to initialize the tipr tooltip in the `customizer.js` file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.has-tooltip').tipr();
});
```

In the customizer this will look like this:
[image]

If it is not what you are looking for, feel no pressure to not accept it as an answer ;)

Comment: Thanks this is somehow what i wanted.
But it works only on input type number and text. Right?
Is there any workaround for other input types like radio, select?

Comment: I did not test it with this control types but I guess you are right. Even if it would work, it would not be ideal I think, because the tip would not show if you hover over the label. I found this article, maybe this will be more usefull for you: [Using tooltips instead of option descriptions in the WordPress Theme Customizer](https://www.gavick.com/blog/using-tooltips-instead-option-descriptions-wordpress-theme-customizer)